# Numerics about the Liouville CFT fusion transformation

Tags: conformal-field-theory, representation-theory

It is known in Liouville CFT from the crossing symmetry that the four points $s$-channel and $t$-channel conformal blocks are related to each other via an integral transformation

$$\mathcal{F}\left[\begin{matrix} \theta_1 , \theta_t \\ \theta_\infty , \theta_0 \end{matrix}; \sigma; t \right]=\int d\rho F_{\sigma, \rho}\mathcal{F}\left[\begin{matrix} \theta_0 , \theta_t \\ \theta_\infty , \theta_1 \end{matrix}; \rho; 1-t \right],$$

where the Liouville fusion kernel $F_{\sigma, \rho}$ has been originally constructed by Ponsot and Teschner in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007097.

The conformal blocks are known explicitly since 2009 thanks to the AGT correspondence, therefore I am wondering if someone has already tried to verify numerically this relation? I haven't found anything on the literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know any direct numerical verification.

This may be because the verification is not terribly easy: the fusion kernel is itself defined by an integral representation, in which the integrand is made of special functions that are themselves defined by integral representations. So there are three integrals to be performed, including the integral over $\rho$.

Also, the verification would not be terribly useful, since there is little doubt that the known formulas for the fusion kernel and conformal blocks are correct.

This said, if I wanted to do the verification, I would not use the [representation of conformal blocks that follows from the AGT correspondence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1312), but rather Zamoldochikov's recursion. (See [here](https://github.com/ribault/bootstrap-2d-Python) for a numerical implementation in Python, and [here](https://github.com/chussong/virasoro) for an implementation in C++.) For the fusion kernel, I would use [Teschner-Vartanov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4698) rather than Ponsot-Teschner.